# Support of Variables for Native Mongo Queries in Metabase

Tags: metabase

I want to add a variable to the given MongoDB query in Metabase. I know that it is supported after https://github.com/metabase/metabase/issues/3653 I have given my query below which is not working with the variable.

My query is:

```
[
  {
    "$project": {
      "lastCommGenTS": "$lastCommGenTS",
      "lastUpdated": "$lastUpdated",
      "regNo": "$regNo",
      "derivedStatus": "$derivedStatus"
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "$expr": {
        "$and": [
          {
            "$eq": [
              "$regNo",{{regNo}}
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": "$_id",
      "regNo": "$regNo",
      "derivedStatus": "$derivedStatus",
      "lastcommtimeIST": {
        "$dateToString": {
          "format": "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",
          "date": {
            "$toDate": "$lastCommGenTS"
          },
          "timezone": "+05:30"
        }
      },
      "lastupdatedIST": {
        "$dateToString": {
          "format": "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",
          "date": {
            "$toDate": "$lastUpdated"
          },
          "timezone": "+05:30"
        }
      },
      "lag_in_minutes": {
        "$divide": [
          {
            "$subtract": [
              "$lastUpdated",
              "$lastCommGenTS"
            ]
          },
          60000
        ]
      }
    }
  }
]
```

I am getting this error here:

```
Unexpected character ('{' (code 123)): was expecting double-quote to start field name at [Source: java.io.StringReader@6bab96b; line: 17, column: 26]
```

Please help me.

Many thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I could not get variables to work for native Mongo Queries because I was using an older version of metabase which did not support the same. The support for variables and field filters in native Mongo queries was added after this version of release - https://github.com/metabase/metabase/releases/tag/v0.34.0